# set environment path in .nsi file without system reboot

Tags: environment-variables, eclipse-rcp, nsis

We are using an eclipse rcp product which is having .nsi file.
So, I want to set the path in environment variables in .nsi file.

I wrote the below piece of code:

```
Section "-Environment"
ReadRegStr $1 HKCU "Environment" "PATH"
;DetailPrint $1
StrCpy $0 $INSTDIR\MKS_Standalone\mkssi
;DetailPrint $0
StrLen $2 $1
;DetailPrint $2
StrLen $3 $0
;DetailPrint $3
IntOp $5 $5 & $5
IntOp $6 $2 - $3
;DetailPrint $6
IntCmp $2 0 labelWrite
labelLoop:
;DetailPrint $5/$6
StrCpy $4 $1 $3 $5
;DetailPrint $4
;DetailPrint $0
StrCmp $4 $0 labelEnd
IntOp $5 $5 + 1
IntCmp $6 $5 labelAdd labelAdd
Goto labelLoop
    labelAdd:
WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "Environment" "PATH" $1;$INSTDIR\MKS_Standalone\mkssi
DetailPrint "Adding path environment."
Goto labelEnd
    labelWrite:
WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "Environment" "PATH" $INSTDIR\MKS_Standalone\mkssi
DetailPrint "Adding path environment."
    labelEnd:
```

SectionEnd

This piece of code is adding the path in environment variables but only after rebooting the machine.
Since my application is running on several machines, I cannot reboot the machine for updating path variables.

How can I set PATH using nsis without system reboot?

Answer (score 0):

- Child processes inherit their parents environment. You can update the installers environment like this: `System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "name", t "value")'`.
- You can announce the change to other running applications like this:

  ```
  !include WinMessages.nsh
  SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_WININICHANGE} 0 "STR:Environment" /TIMEOUT=5000`
  ```

  Explorer.exe is usually the only process that handles this message and reloads its environment.

Comment: Can you please tell where I need to add System::Call in the above section?

Comment: You can add it anywhere but it is only useful if you plan to Exec something on the finish page because it only applies to the installer and child processes started by the installer. You still need the other registry code.

Comment: Also, Could you please tell me,how to remove a path from environment variable in same section mentioned above?

Comment: I can able to remove the user path variable but without admin rights, I cannot remove the path from system variables.
Can you suggest any method through which I can edit/remove the path from system variables without admin rights.

Comment: No, only admins are allowed to change system settings.